# Shared Project access with Forge-bim360APIs [autodesk-bim360]

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I have an account to maintain BIM 360 Docs(ac#1) revisions and shared one of the project to another Bim360 account(ac#2), this account(ac#2) integrated with ForgeApp to invoke Forge web service APIs
wanted to know is it possible to query view projects on ac#2 including ones shared by ac#1 ?
Thanks in advance
Abhinandan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Forge APIs you can access multiple accounts, so move data from Ac#1 to Ac#2 and vice-versa, or even collect data from both and show in a combined screen (on your app, like a *dashboard*).

Just make sure to (1) [provision your Forge App](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/getting-started/get-access-to-account/) within both accounts and (2) be careful to not leak information between accounts.

Comment: Thank you for coming back on this; in my case i specifically want to avoid adding Forge app to AC#1 and add only to AC#2; Whatedver need to be viewed or accessed from AC#1 are shared to AC#2, since AC#2 has Forge integration will it show Shared(from AC#1) as well?

Comment: files are not shared between accounts, per say, if your app needs to see the file on one account, the file must reside there.